# Symfony authentication across two applications

Tags: symfony

I have two apps with distinct install directories and a shared SESSION table (in mysql).

I have multiple authenticators setup on the 'main' app and I can login just fine. When I navigate over to a second app (same domain, different port), Symfony is loading the user from the session and choking somewhere.

I've installed symfony security bundle (in both apps), but made the user and provider non-doctrine in the 2nd.

I am getting this series of exceptions:

**Full authentication is required to access this resource.**

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\
HttpException

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\
InsufficientAuthenticationException

Full authentication is required to access this resource.

Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\
AccessDeniedException

Access Denied.
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session

Suggests that as long as my User object in the second app is identical to the main app - I should be good - alternatively I could implement User::isEqualTo() - which I've done.

It's not even being called, so something way before this is halting my code...

Any thoughts? What have I misconfigured?

Comment: I would assume, that your second app receives a request, finds an unknown session id (since it has its own session storage) and then will not recognize the user (how, anyway?!). that's hardly surprising. if you find that surprising still, maybe I misunderstood your setup and you should add some more information on how exactly you set that up ...

Comment: The remember me-token uses the secret to make sure it is the same application that created the session. Can you check your env if the secrets match? Also, you may want to consider proper sso in the future to allow for independent sessions being controlled through a single entrypoint

Comment: Interesting. They are indeed different. I will make the the same and see what happens :) I've been reading up on the security component and trying a slightly different approach. I am wondering if perhaps a SessionAuthenticator would be the best solution? I just don't understand the internals well enough to know if that'll work or am I way off? I'll clean-up my question here shortly. TIA!!!

Comment: You could implement an oauth server on app A and then authenticate against that server from app B. Without knowing your use case that seems relatively low effort (no separate sso-app), but future proof (if you switch oauth-servers app B only needs to change the host). When your user logs in via app A they use the regular login and once they go to app B they will be redirected to app A and then right back to B. If they log in via B they will get redirected to A, have to login and then get redirected back. You probably want the authorization code-grant type.

Comment: That is essentially what I am trying to achieve, but my approach is not working. Site A has login support for social sites plus its internal authentication/registration. Once they've authenticated there, I want to redirect them to Site X. X being their own instance of Symfony, distinct DB, etc.

Would I use an custom authenticator on site X to grab the session and set the user? This is where my reading has led me...